# Unix: join multiple columns with multiple values based on common column?

Tags: unix, join, sh

So I have two tab-delimited files with two columns which I need to join based on values in common column. The problem is that some values in the common column repeat with different values in the 2nd column... For example:

```
File 1:  
A 3456  
B 234  
A 4509  
A 576  
C 122  
B 235  


File 2:  
A 48556  
A 49  
B 9694  
C 84  
C 96  

Desired Output:  
A 3456 4509 576 48556 49  
B 234 235 9694  
C 122 84 96
```

I am trying to make a "simple" script in Unix that could do this and honestly, do not even know where to start.

Comment: Please tag by clicking on a tag that is offered & read its tag wiki first. JOIN is a category of table operator & doesn't just mean "combine". (You want a certain aggregation of a UNION.)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an **awk** approach joining two files:-

```
awk '
        {
                I[$1]
                A[$1 FS $2]
        }
        END {
                for ( k in I )
                {
                        printf "%s ", k
                        for ( j in A )
                        {
                                split( j, T )
                                if ( T[1] == k )
                                        printf "%d ", T[2]
                        }
                        printf "\n"
                }
        }
' file1 file2
```

Answer (score 1):

FYI, your question is a little misleading.  You don't want a join on a common column.  You want to list all distinct values in N files sharing a common key.  In SQL terms, that's more like what's sometimes called "folding".

Here's one way to do it that comes close to your specified output:

```
$ sort -u -k1  d1 d2 | 
  awk '$1 != prev { if (line) {print line}; prev = $1; line = $0; next;} 
       {line = line " " $2} 
       END{ print line }' 
A 3456 4509 48556 49 576
B 234 235 9694
C 122 84 96
```

Answer (score 0):

Another awk:

```
$ awk '{a[$1]=a[$1] OFS $2}END{for(i in a)print i a[i]}' file1 file2 #...
```

Output is in awk default order:

```
A 3456 4509 576 48556 49
B 234 235 9694
C 122 84 96
```

Explained:

```
$ awk '{
    a[$1]=a[$1] OFS $2   # group by 1st field value by hashing to an array, 
}                        # append 2nd field values to it
END {                    # after processing the data records
    for(i in a)          # iterate all array elements 
        print i a[i]     # print key and value
}' file1 file2           # all the files you want to process
```